# Hypothetical question about a mamzer

Tags: halacha-theory, mamzer

Is someone a mamzer if they were born to an unmarried Jewish woman with an unmarried Jewish guy and were put up for adoption and taken in by a married Jewish couple?

Comment: 2 unmarried people does not a Mamzer equal

Comment: See Mishnah in the 4th chapter of yevamot. Only chayve caret. This excludes your case

Comment: a mamzer is a child born from an adulterous relationship not two unmarried people